# set grafana/influxdb time range based on max and min time of query

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a series of events ranging from 1 to 8 hours that are tagged with a name over the last 2 years. Using the templating function I can move display the different events. My problem is that the time range doesn't rescale when i want to display an event that is outside the currently displayed time range. Ideally I would like to dynamically set the URL with the timestamp encoded from the max and min time of the database (influxdb) query. Any ideas on what I can do?

[Here is a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGqU9.png)

Comment: It would be nice if you have some code or pseudo code to show us to help you make advancements to your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user805981 thanks for the feedback. I added a screenshot to illustrate my problem